# Remove Fabric Causes NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have followed the steps with migrating Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics from

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios

And I have been able to build and run on a simulator until I get to the last step of removing `pod 'Fabric'` from the Podfile. I have confirmed all uses of `Fabric` have been removed from the app. The `Info.plist` file doesn't have the reference and neither does the App's Build Phases Run Script. After I remove `Fabric` and run `Pod update`, when I run the app I get

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20421af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204306f7 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20426036 ___forwarding___ + 1489
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20428068 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   BiggerCity                          0x0000000109878a46 +[FMIceLinkBinary load] + 269
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201804e3 load_images + 1442
    7   ???                                 0x000000010b688e54 0x0 + 4486368852
    8   ???                                 0x000000010b697887 0x0 + 4486428807
    9   ???                                 0x000000010b695bb0 0x0 + 4486421424
    10  ???                                 0x000000010b695c50 0x0 + 4486421584
    11  ???                                 0x000000010b6892a9 0x0 + 4486369961
    12  ???                                 0x000000010b68dd50 0x0 + 4486389072
    13  ???                                 0x000000010b6881c7 0x0 + 4486365639
    14  ???                                 0x000000011647c57a 0x0 + 4668769658
    15  ???                                 0x0000000116479df3 0x0 + 4668759539
    16  ???                                 0x000000011647422b 0x0 + 4668736043
    17  ???                                 0x0000000116474025 0x0 + 4668735525
    18  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM fmSetObj:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000196e130'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 757.3 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (249398DF-8E36-43FB-9144-343355133FBC) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
```

Has anyone seen this error when migrating before? If I add `Fabric` back in the Podfile the error goes away. I've searched my project and all references to `Fabric` are removed.

Comment: `pod update` is for updating existing pods.  If you run `pod install` after removing the `pod 'Fabric'` line from your Podfile it will uninstall that pod.

Comment: When I have done `pod update` or `pod install` it prints the output `Removing Fabric`